# Large indoor gazebo environment

Tags: ros, pepper, gazebo-simu

I'm doing some navigation evaluation in pepper gazebo simulator. So far I've been using my navigation stack on turtlebot3 worlds, but I want to test my stack in a larger environment. Does anyone know are there some lareger already built environments with pre-built map of the environment to use in gazebo?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gazebo has a fairly large range of built-in worlds you can check through [here](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/tree/master/worlds). One that might suit your purpose in the Willow Garage Office world (shown below). If you have gazebo_ros_pkgs installed, you can launch it like so:

```sh
roslaunch gazebo_ros_pkgs willowgarage_world.launch
```

[image: ROS Gazebo Willow Garage Office World]

You can also pick any other world from the folder linked above, and launch it like so:

```sh
roslaunch gazebo_ros_pkgs empty_world.launch --world-name worlds/<world-name>.world
```